# Error Passing this pointer as argument to class constructor

Tags: c++

I have 3 classes 1) GameStateManager 2) MenuState (Inherits from another class called GameState) 3) GameState

I want to pass this pointer as an argument to MenuState's constructor.

My aim is to get a pointer to GameStateManager object in MenuState for future use.

I am getting errors:

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'GameStateManager'
error C2664: 'MenuState::MenuState(const MenuState &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'GameStateManager' to 'const MenuState &'
note: Reason: cannot convert from 'GameStateManager' to 'const MenuState'
```

**GameStateManager.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "MenuState.h"

class GameStateManager {
public:
    static const int MENUSTATE = 0;
    static const int FIRSTLEVELSTATE = 1;

    GameStateManager();

    ~GameStateManager();
private:
    std::vector<GameState*> States;
    int currentState;
};
```

**GameStateManager.cpp**

```
GameStateManager::GameStateManager() {
    this->currentState = MENUSTATE;
    this->States.push_back(new MenuState(*this)); // Error Line. I Think!
}
```

**MenuState.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "GameState.h"
#include "GameStateManager.h"
class MenuState: public GameState{
public:
    MenuState(GameStateManager& gsm);
    ~MenuState();
};
```

**MenuState.cpp**

```
MenuState::MenuState(GameStateManager& gsm){ // Error Line. I Think!
}
```

**GameState.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
class GameState {
//Virtual methods are here in this code which are not important for this question
public:
    GameState() {}
    ~GameState() {}
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "GameStateManager.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    GameStateManager gsm;
}
```

Comment: You have a circular include path dependency. Does `MenuState.h` really need to include GameStateManager.h? I mean a forward declaration of GameStateManager and removing #include "GameStateManager.h" from MenuStat.h could fix that.

Comment: The error message is referring to a copy constructor. The "Error Line"s have nothing to do with a copy constructor context. You need to edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: ***error C2664: 'MenuState::MenuState(const MenuState &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'GameStateManager' to 'const MenuState &'*** This error is caused by code that is not presented.

Comment: No, you didn't "updated the question with minimal code that could cause a problem". If you don't understand how to provide a [mcve], this question should simply be closed accordingly.

Comment: ***error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'GameStateManager'*** I believe is caused by the circular include. MenuState.h includes GameStateManager.h and GameStateManager.h includes MenuState.h

Comment: The problem with the circular include is `GameStateManager` will be undefined when the compiler processes  `MenuState(GameStateManager& gsm);` in MenuState.h because of the circular include. Although MSVC usually complains with `c++` does not support default int in this case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik After commenting out everything in my code keeping what i shared in question, error still persists. So trust me when i tell you this. All code is there that could cause a problem.

Comment: @Sam I would fix the circular include first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since like the header inclusion conflict in `GameStateManager.h` and `MenuState.h`

Use the forward declaration if they are declared as pointers or references:

1. `MenuState::MenuState(class GameStateManager& gsm);`
2. `std::vector<class MenuState*> States;`

Then, put the line `#include "GameStateManager.h"` into `MenuState.cpp` and put the line `#include "MenuState.h"` into `GameStateManager.h` would reduce the error.

Comment: Just adding MenuState::MenuState(class GameStateManager& gsm) fixed the problem. But i was wondering, was the issue raised due to my bad structuring of the code or is it something else?

Comment: The cross reference of classes by using pointer or reference is common. However, the pointer or reference needs the name of the type rather then the definition of the type. It is not need to include the header unless the access of the member of the type.